# Where's result of System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine?

Tags: .net

In my code, I wrote some trace messages by using `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine`, but where could I get the messages? I have looked at Event Viewer but didn't find them.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Are you debugging? Look at the "Output" Tab (`View` | `Output`, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) in Visual Studio.

If it's not outputting there, you need to add [a listener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx).

Check [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx).

Comment: Note: For most projects the compiler flag `TRACE` should be on by default in Visual Studio.  For ASP.Net you've got to have a `compilers` section in Web.config with `compilerOptions="/d:TRACE"`.

Comment: adding listener as in above "listener" link helped me + compilerOptions - it is just that i had to set autoflush="true" just to see it work in time

Answer (score 6):

Virtually, the key feature of Trace is that the trace messages are *independent* from the IDE basically. Because trace messages are also available in the release build, you can also get them, when the software was already shipped and/or you have no IDE in avail.
You guessed right, there is a tool, which makes you see those messages apart from VS. If you are not debugging (i.e. no debug-console allocated in VS), you can see the trace messages with the tool **Debugview** running in parallel instead of Windows' EventViewer. It is also possible to write trace messages to a file by editing/creating a *.config file accompanying the assembly in question, which also records the history of messages.